# Excel function cell reference

Tags: excel

I want to sum a range,for example column A.

normal method would be Sum(A50:A81).

I'm trying to sum A50 and add 31 rows Dynamically. Something like Sum(A50:(A50+31)).Basically just add 31 rows with a cell.How do i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are looking for something like:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A50,0,0,31))
```

Please check out the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)-function to adjust the formula if you need it ;)

Comment: OFFSET(A50,0,0,31) is to retrieve the value of A81, the function you provided is basically =sum(A(81).VALUE) t.t.....

Comment: No... `OFFSET(A50,31)` would do that. But `OFFSET(A50,0,0,31)` returns the whole range from A50 to A81 like A30:A81 would do. it is `OFFSET([root],[shift up/down],[shift left/right],[set height],[set width])` while height/width extends down/right from the first cell. please read the the official help from the link i have provided...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following non Volatile function:

```
=SUM(A50:INDEX(A:A,Row(A50)+31))
```